# primitive type float with unicode characters in java

Tags: java, unicode, primitive, floating

why below line of code will not give me any compilation error

```
public class Test4
{

public static void main(String...a)
{
        float f = \u0038;//Line 1
        long L2 = 3L;
        float fd = (float) 2.2;
        char c = '\u005E';
        byte e = 100;

}
}
```

line 1 `float f = \u0038;` will not give me any compilation error

and if it is unicode charectors then can we use them with 
float,double,int and other primitive type.
what are the standard to use unicode charectors with primitive type
and if yes then why we can use it??

thanks

Comment: `\u0038` is just short-hand for `8`.

Answer (score 0):

float has **32 bits** and a range between **±1.4E-45 to ±3.4028235E+38**
Unicode has **16 bits** and a range between **\u0000 to \uFFFF or 0 ... 65535**
Therefore float f = \u0038 works because float format larger than char format. So nothing gets lost. But if you reverse the assignments as following you'll see the work of casting and the significant meaning of a format.

```
float f = \u0038;   // OK because 16 bits fit a format of 32 bits
char x = (char) f;  // no complaint because you "explicitly" cast f 
                    // and take risk of losing precision
char y = f;         // javac will complains "error: possible loss of precision" 
                    // in order to warn you about the hidden "bugs" you might get...
```